# Apache Client Authentication : Certificate Verification: Error (2): unable to get issuer certificate (SOLVE)

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, ssl-client-authentication

I am trying to configure a server with client authentication on a directory and Certificate Revocation List (crl). I succeeded once to make the client client authentication works but is is not anymore and I never succeeded in making the revocation list works.

Here are my configuration files :

- default-ssl.conf

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html      
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /root/ca/intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /root/ca/intermediate/private/www.example.com.key.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /root/ca/intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile    /root/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem  
        
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory> 
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

- apache2.conf

```html
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/testClientCert>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     SSLVerifyClient require
     SSLVerifyDepth 10
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
```

I used the following tuto to create root and intermediate AC : https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ (part 1 and 2)

I used the following command to generate client certificate :

4 - Create client certificate
    4.1 Create the client key
        openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 4096

```
4.2 Create the client csr
    openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr

4.3 Create the client certificate
    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA /root/ca/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem -CAkey /root/ca/intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem -set_serial <mettre une valeur à changer à chaque cert genre à incrémenter (01 pour le premier puis 02...> -out client.crt

4.4 Convert client certificate to PKCS
    openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12
```

Now here is my question, it seems my intermediate certificate is not trusted, indeed when I try to access the directory /var/www/html/testClientCert with Mozilla (I imported intermediate AC + client cert in Mozilla), I have the following error :

```html
tail -f 20 /var/log/apache2/*

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2017:20:15:48 +0200] "GET /testClientCert/gg.txt HTTP/1.1" 403 9768 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Mon Aug 07 20:15:48.741592 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 2262:tid 140536910403328] [client 127.0.0.1:55376] AH02039: Certificate Verification: Error (2): unable to get issuer certificate
[Mon Aug 07 20:15:48.741670 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 2262:tid 140536910403328] [client 127.0.0.1:55376] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
[Mon Aug 07 20:15:48.741687 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 2262:tid 140536910403328] SSL Library Error: error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

How comes error occurs whereas I signed the intermediate AC cert with the root AC cert and that my client certificate is signed by intermediate AC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone needs the answer, I post it. The comment in default configuration file (default-ssl.conf) lead me in the good track :

```
    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
```

So the file SSLCACertificateFile must contain the root and intermediate certificate. Then the change of this line solves my problem :

**SSLCACertificateFile /root/ca/intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem**

I have not find the solution for crl yet, I post it when I find it.